# How to apply a cumulative python function for specific time-periods within a day and then reset from the very next day

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series

I am applying a time series cumulative function for a specific number of time periods let say 15 min to a series of days
my main function is:

```
def axmp(df):
    return np.cumsum(df.Volume * (df.High + df.Low + df.Close)/3) / np.cumsum(df.Volume)
```

But i fail to apply the above function to a pandas data frame consisting of 15 min stock data by the pandas groupby method.

As in the above function in i want an addition to reset the above python function at the the begining of each new day (i.e it should not take any cumulative figures from the previous days) and should continue over a year of stock data.

Sample data:

```
        Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume
13-02-2019 9:15 65.89   65.89   65.89   65.89   24339
13-02-2019 9:30 66.00   66.00   66.00   66.00   1892
14-02-2019 11:15 65.98  65.98   65.98   65.98   1937
14-02-2019 11:30 65.95  66.01   65.95   66.01   5181
15-02-2019 9:15 66.04   66.08   66.04   66.08   6189
```

Please Suggest me any modification to the above code or a new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need to apply `axmp` having grouped by day:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['new_col'] = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.day).apply(axmp).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
          Date         Open   High    Low   Close  Volume    new_col
0 2019-02-13 09:15:00  65.89  65.89  65.89  65.89   24339  65.890000
1 2019-02-13 09:30:00  66.00  66.00  66.00  66.00    1892  65.897934
2 2019-02-14 11:15:00  65.98  65.98  65.98  65.98    1937  65.980000
3 2019-02-14 11:30:00  65.95  66.01  65.95  66.01    5181  65.987279
4 2019-02-15 09:15:00  66.04  66.08  66.04  66.08    6189  66.066667
```

Comment: @yatu Applying your code the new column shows only NaN values in the dataframe

Comment: @Wen-Ben Its not exactly a rolling question

Comment: Works fine for me @ScrappyCoco. Is the date in datetime format?  Use the new line otherwise